# How can I initiate a shutdown to an instance after certain time from when it started?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, scheduled-tasks, instance

I have instances in GCP.
I can schedule a time to start and stop using the scheduler.
But, I don't want a specific time of the day, I want a specific time *after* instance was started.

For example - Stop the instance after 8 hours the instance is up and running.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the contents of a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts) directly to a VM when you create the VM.

You can also pass a Linux startup script directly to an existing VM:

In your Cloud Console go to VM Instance page and click on the instance you want to pass the start up script

1. Click Edit.
2. Under Automation, specify the following:

```
 #! /bin/bash
shutdown -P +60
```

`-P`    Instructs the system to shut down and then power down.

The *time* argument specifies when to perform the shutdown operation.

The *time* can be formatted in different ways:

First, it can be an absolute *time* in the format `hh:mm`, where `hh` is the hour (1 or 2 digits, from 0 to 23) and `mm` is the minute of the hour (in two digits).

Second, it can be in the format `+m`, where **`m` is the number of minutes to wait.**

Also, the word `now` is the same as specifying `+0`; it shuts the system down immediately.

Answer (score 1):

In the Google Console, if you go to your VM and click on "Edit" yout can set a time limit for the VM in the "Management" section

[image]

From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/schedule-instance-start-stop) of this preview feature:

> Automatic termination lets you schedule a VM to be terminated (stopped or deleted) when it reaches a specific time limit (duration or time).